# Compare two dates inside the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got an error on Where clause "X" when execute this query

```
select top 100 DATEADD(HOUR,10, DateCreated) as X
from y
where X between '2015 -03-31 ' and '2015 -04 -02' 
order by DateCreated desc
```

Comment: you can't use the alias in the `WHERE` clause, you have to use the full field, ie `DATEADD(HOUR,10, DateCreated)` also, mysql doesn't support `TOP 100` style syntax, so either your tags are wrong, or your query is wrong there too

Comment: Use DATEADD(HOUR,10, DateCreated) in where clause instead of X

Comment: okay..i am query table y in db server...when i execute the same query the error message i got was "Invalid Column name "X"

Comment: select DATEADD(HOUR,10, DateCreated) as X from y where DATEADD(HOUR,10, DateCreated) between '2015 -03-31 ' and '2015 -04 -02' order by DateCreated desc LIMIT 100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logical order of query processing phases is:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

As you can see `SELECT` is happening after `WHERE`. So you cannot use any of the aliases of your `SELECT` part in `WHERE` clause. You can only use the aliases in `ORDER BY`.

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 DATEADD(HOUR, 10, DateCreated) AS X
FROM y
WHERE DATEADD(HOUR, 10, DateCreated) BETWEEN '2015-03-31' AND '2015-04-02' 
ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
```

Also I suggest you to use

```
WHERE DATEADD(HOUR, 10, DateCreated) >= '2015-03-31'
AND DATEADD(HOUR, 10, DateCreated) <= '2015-04-02'
```

[LOGICAL QUERY PROCESSING](http://www.sqlabout.com/logical-query-processing/)

[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 1):

X is alias name of column,so you can not use it directly in where clause.

```
select top 100 DATEADD(HOUR,10, DateCreated) as X
from Table_1
where DATEADD(HOUR,10, DateCreated) between '2015 -03-31 ' and '2015 -04 -02' 
order by DateCreated desc
```